# How do I sequentially go down a list of links each time a user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I start with a button that activates the function onclick:

```
<button onclick="openStuff();">Click here!</button>
```

Then, I have an array of links like so:

```
var links = [
    "msn.com",
    "google.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "bbc.com",
    "facebook.com",
    "cnn.com",
    "fox.com",
    "techcrunch.com"];
```

Finally, I define the function that randomly applies a link to the button from the above array:

```
openStuff = function () {
    // get a random number between 0 and the number of links
    var randIdx = Math.random() * links.length;
    
    // round it, so it can be used as array index
    randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);

    // construct the link to be opened
    var link = 'https://' + links[randIdx];

    // open it in a new window / tab (depends on browser setting)
    window.open(link);
};
```

The problem is I need it to not be random. Rather, I need it to go down the list sequentially as the user clicks the button. If the user clicks the button once it should go to the first link. But, if this user clicks the button a second time it should go to the second link in the list.

For example: User clicks button: Go to first link, User clicks button again: go to second link, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var linkIndex = 0;
openStuff = function () {
    //when no more links are available to click then return
    if(links.length <= linkIndex) return;

    // construct the link to be opened
    var link = 'https://' + links[linkIndex];

    // open it in a new window / tab (depends on browser setting)
    window.open(link);

    linkIndex++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a global index that start in 0. Then, inside the function you increment it after open the link.

```
var link = 'https://' + links[index];
index++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```js
var special_button_state = 0;
const links = [
    "msn.com",
    "google.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "bbc.com",
    "facebook.com",
    "cnn.com",
    "fox.com",
    "techcrunch.com"
    ];

const openStuff = function () {
    var link = 'https://' + links[special_button_state];
    if(special_button_state < links.length-1) {
        special_button_state++;
    }
    window.open(link);
    console.log(link);
};
```

```html
<button onclick="openStuff();">Click here!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have another variable set to the first index of the array, something like:

```
var linkTarget = 0
```

and then update linkTarget in the function to increment appropriately:

```
openStuff = function () {
    // construct the link to be opened
    var link = 'https://' + links[linkTarget];

    // open it in a new window / tab (depends on browser setting)
    window.open(link);

    // update the index
    if (linkTarget++ == links.length)
        linkTarget = 0
};
```

---

You could also implement a dynamic label so that you know where it's going:

```
<body onload="setLink()">
    <button id="turntable-button" onclick="openStuff()" />
</body>
```

Label setter on page load (put the same `getElementById()` line in `openStuff()` after updating the index):

```
setLink = function() {
    document.getElementById("turntable-button").innerHTML = links[linkTarget];
}
```